# How to refer to a relative position within a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've included an external image in a TikZ diagram as follows:

```
\node (A) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image.png}};
```

The image is 100x100 pixels, and I need to draw a path from pixel (64,32). Is there a way to refer to the position 64% from the left and 32% from the bottom inside the node?